# jQuery remove all HTML tags EXCEPT Anchors

Tags: jquery, html

Currently, I have this line:

```
this.html(this.html().replace(/\x3C\x2F?[^\x3E]+\x3E/gi, ''));
```

But, I would like something along the lines of an "if clause" to say,

```
IF (this.tag = "<a") {
  do nothing
} ELSE {
  remove tag
}
```

I don't suppose anyone has any ideas?

**[EDIT]: I think I may have to do a "FOR EACH" loop... I think.... [/EDIT]**

^.^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.html(this.html().replace(/<\/?([b-z]+)[^>]*>/gi, function(match, tag) { 
  return (tag === "a") ? match : ""; 
}));
```

If you are looking at leaving the "a" tags in place, change the regular expression from `[a-z]` to `[b-z]`

Comment: That will keep all tags **containing** an "a", like `span`. Apart from that it's exactly the same as mine, which supposedly doesn't work...

Answer (score 4):

jQuery has ":not" pseudo-selector.

```
$(':not(a)', this).remove()
```

Comment: This is the best answer hands-down. Tackling regex for this seems entirely unnecessary when you can combine jQuery selectors like this.

Answer (score 2):

`replace` can take a function as the second parameter

```
this.html(this.html().replace(/<\/?([a-z]+)[^>]*>/gi, function(match, tag) {
  return (tag.toLowerCase() === "a") ? match : "";
}));
```

I didn't use the hex encoded chars because it's easier to read this way.

Comment: This is the right IF statement!! But I would like to keep the links exactly as they are. This seems to replace the link with something else :(

Comment: Could it be that your tags are uppercase. I forgot to consider that. Edited.