# How do I block HTML in my form input?

Tags: php, html, html-entities

So, I have a basic little script that takes input from an HTML form, is processes by PHP and then writes it to a text file in the form of CSS. I've already got some jerkwad trying to drop tables on the server (There is no SQL but I'd like to keep people from trying none the less) Here is the code that I have thus far, can someone help me block potentially bad input via htmlentities or something else?

**The HTML Form**

```
<html><body>
<h4>Codes Form</h4>
<form action="codes.php" method="post"> 

Username: <input name="Username" type="text" />
Usercode: <input name="Usercode" type="text" /> 

<input type="submit" value="Post It!" />
</form>
</body></html>
```

**The PHP**

```
    <html><body>
 <?php 

 $Friendcode = $_POST['Usercode'];
 $Username = $_POST['Username'];

echo "You have recorded the following information on the server ". $Username . " " . $Usercode . ".<br />"; echo "Thanks for contributing!";


$output = ".author[href\$=\"$Username\"]:after { \n"
       ."content: \" ($Usercode)\" !important\n"
       ."}";
}
$fp = fopen('file.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $output);
fwrite($fp, "\n");
fclose($fp);
?>


</body></html>
```

Comment: no need to encode your html and wrap in `<pre>` tags. Just post codes, select block and hit CTRL+K :)

Comment: http://php.net/strip_tags, http://php.net/filter and http://php.net/ctype

Comment: Thanks, I was having a hell of a time getting it to block for me lol. Guess theres a reason that I'm here :P

Answer (score 2):

You can use [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to convert html tags to their html equiv. < etc. Or you can use [strp_tags](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to get rid of all html tags. If you are using sql use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to make sql queries safer

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you include data entered by the user in **HTML code**, it is always a good idea to first encode the data, by passing it into `htmlspecialchars()`.

Think of it as a decontamination chamber.  This will ensure that any of the HTML special chacters, such as "<" and ">" (deadly viruses) are properly escaped (killed) and won't show up in your page as "real" HTML tags (won't make your webpage sick).

Similarly, you must also encode user input when including it in **SQL queries**.  The function that you use for this purpose varies depending on the database that you are using.  Because of the dynamic nature of PHP, if you are a including numeric value in a SQL query, you must first check to make sure the variable contains a number by using functions such as `is_numeric()` and `ctype_digit()`.

Comment: I've been inundated by feedback here haha. So, using everyones feedback, I've found two points that I believe will solve my issue. This particular script doesn't write the output to anything other than a text file so SQL injections aren't a threat (not running sql) That being said, I'd like to keep people from trying, as it writes garbage to my file. Also, the isset $POST line would be great as a blank entry ruins the css in the output. Where I'm lost, is how to incorporate htmlentities and the Isset $POST lines in the script. I'm not sure what string to apply it to and to the html or the php?

Comment: @Zer0mod This idea of filtering input is an especially important one that many people forget about.  I think it's safe to say that it is the source of the majority of security flaws found in web applications today.  You should use `htmlentities()` whenever you are outputting the data to HTML (whenever you "echo" anything).  By the way, your PHP code is filled with syntax errors and does not work.

Comment: It works fine, I just realized that when it was edited a lot of it is missing. which ruins this question really. Thanks for noticing that. It actually uses fwrite to output to a txt file. There i've edited it. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to block HTML is to allow only the characters you think a username or a user code may have.

For example, limit the input to letters, numbers and underscores and trim the whitespaces in the beginning and the end of the string. This validation will fail whenever HTML code is provided as input.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing this on both client and server side, with a regex. A client-side example can be found here: [jQuery remove all HTML tags EXCEPT Anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083225/jquery-remove-all-html-tags-except-anchors)

Answer (score 0):

What happen if someone directly type the url of `code.php` in browser. They will get the Notice of undefined offset.

You should make at least a check if `$_POST` is not empty.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST))
{
  //do operation
}
```

Validate the user name and user code for special characters and what you allow them to enter with PHP sever side

Comment: I've tried the above and have added a simple { echo "you must enter a value"; } line, but this causes the form to break. I'm not sure how to incorporate this into my php. Does it matter that the .php file is seperate from the html? Or am I missing something really obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

@Zer0mod: I'd use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to get rid of HTML and [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to take care of any potential SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP to convert every symbol to HTML numbers! Head on over to [htmlentities()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) for details about doing so.