# Jquery remove everything except for bolded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector, jsoup

I have html like this:

```
<div id="divTestArea1">
    <b>Bold text</b>
    <i>Italic text</i>
    <div id="divTestArea2">
            <b>Bold text 2</b>
            <i>Italic text 2</i>
            <div>
                    <b>Bold text 3</b>
            </div>
    </div>
```

and I would like to remove all elements that aren't bold. I've tried with this code:

```
$('*:not(b)').remove();
```

and a couple other variations but they all either error out or remove everything. btw, are jquery selectors and jsoup selectors 100% compatible? I'd like to use the answer to this in jsoup as well.

Comment: Here is something similar to your question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083225/jquery-remove-all-html-tags-except-anchors

Comment: In your example the `<b>` elements don't contain other elements, but what do you want to do if a particular `<b>` has, say, a nested `<i>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current code removes the document `<body>` as well as all `<div>`s which contain the `<b>` tags.  If you only want to save the bold text then Shih-En Chou's solution works well.  If you want to save the `<div>` structure that the `<b>` tags are in as well you could do this:

```
$("body *:not(div, b)")​​​​.remove();​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Snowsickle/UfUPp/)

Answer (score 3):

My solution:

I clone `<b>`  and save it into memory.
->Remove all
-> insert `<b>` into `<body>`

here is my code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/sechou/43ENq/

```
$(function(){
   var tmpB = $("b").clone();
   $('body').remove();
   $("body").append(tmpB);
});​
```

Comment: if you are cloning the b then why we need this statement  $('body *:not(b)').remove() why we cant use  $('body').remove();

Comment: if we remove <body>. How can <b> be inserted into document XD?

Comment: $('body *:not(b)').remove(); in this statement you are not removing b so why need to clone them and append

Answer (score 2):

Move all elements in `#divTestArea2` as it is a `div` and will be removed as well to `#divTestArea1`, then filter out anything that is'nt a `<b>` and remove it :

```
$("#divTestArea1").append($("*", "#divTestArea2")).find('*').filter(function() {
    return this.tagName !== 'B';
}).remove();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmXDr/)

The above keeps the `#divTestArea1` element intact, to remove *everything* but the `<b>` elements, something like :

```
$('body')​.append($('b'))​.find('*')​.not('b')​.remove();​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmXDr/1/)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/).

```
var $body = $("body");
var $b = $("b", $body).detach();
$(":not(b)", $body).remove();​​​​​​​​​​​
$body.append($b);
```

This way you don't need to either move or clone anything to overcome the problem of the deletion of the objects wrapping your `<b/>` elements.

[(demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/BJK2x/)

Comment: But you are moving the elements, only difference is you're detaching the elements before you reinsert them, while just using append would simply move the elements directly in the DOM ?

Comment: @adeneo, it's good to see that you came up with that after reading mine. Though, the outcome is the same, `detach` and `append`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// Find all the <b> tags and unwrap them so they all become siblings and finally 
// remove non <b> siblings
$('body').find('b').unwrap().siblings('*:not(b)').remove();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3f2Hu/